# How to retain value of static variable inside a same class which has 2 implementations

Tags: c++, static

I have to call a static functions inside a class(say UserApp) which returns static value.
Class Definition and declaration done in 2 files.

File1.h:

```
userApp(){

    static int* foo;
}
```

file1.cpp:

```
{
    int* userApp::foo = 0;
    ...
    .
    .

    foo = somevar;

}
```

The same class(userApp) is implemented in file2 and to avoid linkage error I'm forced to declare and define the static variable in file2 as well.

In file 2.cpp as userApp::foo is initialized to 0 , the return value of function getFoo is always zero.

I need the value associated to foo in file1.
Is there any way I can avoid defining static variable in file2?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What a mess :D

If I understood you right, I believe you have to declare the static member as extern in one of the files, to indicate it's actually referencing to a variable declared elsewhere.

Comment: Two files has declaration and implementation of same class[with some variations in functionalities].Thus the static member variables and functions are to be defined in both r8?

Comment: Aw, now wait... You are defining the same class in a different way in each file and including both files?

Comment: That won't work because then it's impossible to tell to which foo you are referring. Give a different name to each class and decide when you want class1::foo or class2::foo. If you want them both to be the same, again, make two different classes and make one of them's foo refer to the other one's foo.

Comment: If you define a class twice, when you call class::foo, how to know which implementation are you calling?

Answer (score 0):

In *UserApp.h*:

```
class UserApp {
private:
    static int* foo_;
public:
    static int* getFoo() { return foo_; }
};
```

In *UserApp.cpp*:

```
#include "UserApp.h"

int* UserApp::foo_ = NULL;
```

In any other where you need to use it:

```
#include "UserApp.h"
...
int* foo = UserApp::getFoo();
```

You haven't provided any details about your `namespace` / `class` full of `static` things, but consider making more OO design or in case it seems reasonable to keep it in one class, consider implementing a ***singleton*** that would also allow you to hold the information about its state in more reasonable way. (you might end up with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19214185/1168156))